# Reject email if From address matches and if content matches as well (Postifx)

Tags: debian, postfix, spam

I'm trying to setup a rule in my postfix configuration where I check the from address and the email content.

My idea is to REJECT mail if:

```
From: test@test.com
Content: Hello Test
```

Is there anyway to check mail content from header_checks? Or finding the from address in the body_content?

I was thinking in a simple regexp like this:

```
/^From:test@test.com && Content:.*Hello Test.*$/
```

But it's not working because I can either check from header or from body. How could I achieve this situation?

Thank you

Comment: You can achieve this by using by policies http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html, but personally I'd use some sort of (spam)filtering software (e.g. rspamd, amavis, etc.) for this stuff. Custom policies can be quite the hassle.

Comment: I'm doing some research on respamd as well. Problem is that we're getting targetted by spambots who are using AOL mail system. And it's painfull because I cannot simply reject all incoming email from aol. All emails addresses seems to be auto generated by some bot so it won't get triggered by any anti spam filtering software. I'll give a look also on that link. Thank you

Comment: 99,99999% of spam mails are auto-generated. If you use some form of spamfiltering, most of the time you can create own filters for your problem specifically, or use scoring systems, etc. etc.